# RxTx crashes when upgrading from Java 8 to Java 10

Tags: 64-bit, rxtx, java-10, windows-10-desktop

I have an application running `RxTxCOMM` on Windows 10 64 bit with Java 8.

This app uses USB serial port adapters, because the newer PCS do not have enough serial ports. I updated Java 8 to Java 10 and the RxTxCOMM does not work.

On Java 10. when there are no USB adapters plugged in, the app works and successfully gets the

> serial port not found errors

but it immediately crashes when I plug in an *USB Serial Adapter*.

Comment: I tried to improve your question, but I may have failed. Please correct my edit if you do know better.

Comment: To isolate the issue, I created a program that only tries to read data from a serial port. I created 2 jar files using intellij. One version was created with this sdk: jdk1.8.0_171. 
One version was created with this sdk:jdk-10.0.2
Both versions work on a PC with java 8. Version 8 Update 181 (build 1.8.0_181-b13) 
Niether Version work on a PC with  Java 10. Version 10.0.2 (build 10.0.2+13) amd64.

Comment: I have two versions in of a project that uses RxTxCOMM in  intelij, one is jdk 8, one is jdk10. Both use the same RxTxCOMM.jar and the same RxTxserial.dll. The jdk 8  version works and starts the RxTx thread successfully, but the jdk 10 version does not start the RxTx thread successfully. Any thought as to why starting a thread would be different in the 2 versions? When I run the 2 different projects in debugger in intellij. Different java code is executed when the RxTx thread starts. I seems that something in the java-10 version is different than JAVA 8 so the same DLL does not work in both.

Comment: I cannot answer your question, but it would be better, if you'd add additional information to the question itself with an edit instead of comments.